# VBA - How to disable "record macro"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

Lower left corder of screen (in status bar), there is a squar icon for "record macro".  Wow, that's dangerous for my secret macro codes.  How to disable this?  Could not find a satisfactory answer on google.

Answer (score 1):

Macro recording is an integrated part of Excel and you can't just disable that button and expect it to work everywhere.

Luckily it is not required to actually disable that button if you just want to protect your macro code. You can put a password on the macro itself from within the VBA editor. By protecting the file, you will have to enter a password in order to make changes to the file. Executing macros from that file do not require a password though.

That said, it is very unlikely you really need to do this unless you are building a spreadsheet with password protected sheets and macros that are required to be used and you want to prevent people from finding out the passwords for the sheets.

The reason is that most people don't even can't code in VisualBasic and are not interested in this even if they saw the code, and others are smart enough to build what you are creating themselves anyway. It is often the small group that wants to access the code that can't build it themselves because the code is not working and they want to troubleshoot and fix the issue. You generally do not want to exclude them unless this whole sheet thingy is something people pay money for, but then excel with VBA macro's really is not the best solution anyway.

Now having said that, it is not too hard to hack into an excelsheet and extract anything, even if you protect it the best you can. The only real protection that is guaranteed to hold, is simply not using excel with VBA. Then you can be guaranteed that no one can get to your secred macro codes.

Comment: Thank you, Chip... But my concern is that they click on "record macro" and paste in a set of codes that would extract my codes... huhuhu....  I want to kill this icon, how to gray out or delete or cover up the icon...?

Comment: The record macro cannot extract your code, so you don't have to worry about that. It can execute it, but not actually read it.